# What is part / whole?

Tags: terminology, percentages

For example,

$$\frac{\text{part}}{\text{whole}} \cdot 100 = \text{percentage}$$

**Example**

$$\frac{1}{4} \cdot 100 \%$$

What is the quantity $\frac{\text{part}}{\text{whole}}$ called?

From the above example, it would yield $0.25$; what is the mathematical term for this quantity?

Comment: You mean *Fraction*? *Relative Potion*?

Comment: Is `fraction` the most appropriate mathematical term?

Comment: Well, your specific example seems to always be a **rational** fraction between $0$ and $1$, so I would say that *Portion* (a private case of *Fraction*) is more appropriate here.

Comment: "proportion" is a term that's commonly used here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your specific example seems to be a rational number (fraction) between $0$ and $1$.

So the term *Portion* (a private case of *Fraction*) would probably be the most appropriate.

Comment: Nice answer but may I ask why it is not appropriate to term the given simply as fraction? Im just curious... Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JrAntalan: Thanks :) A fraction can also be negative, or larger than $1$ or smaller than $1$. For example $\frac{22}{7}$. As I mentioned in the answer, the specific example at hand (`Part / Whole`) is sort of a private case of a fraction, i.e., only rational numbers between $0$ and $1$. It is in fact a relative portion of something (i.e., "a part of a whole", just as OP has described it).

Comment: Now I know and I definitely agree with you thanks.